# How to avoid Compile error: Expected End Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to implement cell counting by coloring with VBA you can check here (>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/count-cells-number-with-color-using-vba).
Issue is that return me every time **Compile error:  Expected End Sub** and i don't know how to avoid it. Before this lines of code i have 2 End Sub-s which works well.

```
Sub Color()

Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
       CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax

End Function
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't have a `Function... End Function` inside a `Sub...End Sub`.

Comment: Oh, changing now.

Comment: Thanks **BigBen** its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Function` and `Sub` blocks can't be nested like that. Each must be separate, with an opening `Sub` or `Function` line, and an `End Sub`/`End Function` line enclosing the code.

```
Sub Color()
...
End Sub

Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
...
End Function
```

To call `CountCcolor` within `Color`:

```
Sub Color()
     ...
     Dim myCount as Long
     myCount = CountCcolor(rng1, rng2)
End Sub
```

Comment: How to call function in row starting from cell F11 and go in the forward until no color to count anymore. 
Or the other option is preordered number of rows, starting from F11 to **O11** (10, 15, 25).

Comment: Can you ask that as a new question? Preferably one issue per question, and that is a new issue.